# How to notify UIViewController's UINavigationController to push another UIViewController on navigation stack using Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, combine

I'm trying to notify my `TUCSearchRepoListViewController` to push one of the controllers on top of navigation stack based on action that happen inside of the `TUCRepositoryListView`.

The `TUCRepositoryListView` holds a UITableView with a custom cell of type `TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell` that has two action.
One is for opening the `TUCRepositoryDetailsViewController` by pressing on the text, and another one is for opening `TUCUserDetailsViewController` by pressing the UIImageView.

**Issue: By tapping on the cells text or image, new UIViewController is not being pushed to navigation stack.**

I'm using the MVVM design pattern and I separated the View from the UIViewController.

I understand that this is a lot of code, so if it's easier for you, here is the link to the [Git repository](https://github.com/FilipVarda97/TestUndabotCombine) with full code.

Here is my code of `TUCSearchRepoListViewController`:

```
import SnapKit
import Combine

/// Initial controller for the app. This controller presents TURepositoryListView which supports searching for repos and sorting them.
final class TUCSearchRepoListViewController: UIViewController {
    private let repoListView = TUCRepositoryListView(frame: .zero)
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    // MARK: - Implementation
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Repositories"
        setUpViews()
    }

    private func setUpViews() {
        navigationItem.searchController = repoListView.searchController
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(repoListView)
        repoListView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
    }

    private func bind() {
        repoListView.openRepositoryDetails
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] repository in
                let viewModel = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewModel(repository: repository)
                let vc = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
        repoListView.openUserDetails
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] url in
                let viewModel = TUCUserDetailsViewModel(userUrl: url)
                let vc = TUCUserDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Here is the `TUCRepositoryListView`:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Combine

/// A view holding a table view that presents cells with repository information,
/// and UISearchController with it's ScopeButtons.
final class TUCRepositoryListView: UIView {
    private let viewModel = TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel()
    private let input = PassthroughSubject<TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel.Input, Never>()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    public let openUserDetails = PassthroughSubject<URL, Never>()
    public let openRepositoryDetails = PassthroughSubject<TUCRepository, Never>()

    public let searchController: UISearchController = {
        let searchController = UISearchController()
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Repository name"
        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Stars", "Forks", "Updated"]
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        return searchController
    }()
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell.self,
                       forCellReuseIdentifier: TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        table.separatorStyle = .none
        return table
    }()
    private let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.style = .large
        return spinner
    }()

    // MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()
        setUpConstraints()
        configureView()
        bind()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Unsupported")
    }

    // MARK: - Implementation
    private func bind() {
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        output
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { event in
                switch event {
                case .didBeginLoading:
                    self.beginLoadingRepositories()
                case .failedToLoadSearchRepositories:
                    self.failedToLoadSearchRepositories()
                case .finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories:
                    self.finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories()
                case .openUserDetails(userUrl: let userUrl):
                    self.openUserDetails(userUrl: userUrl)
                case .openRepositoryDetils(repository: let repository):
                    self.openRepositoryDetails(repository: repository)
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private func setUpViews() {
        addSubviews(tableView, spinner)
    }

    private func setUpConstraints() {
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        spinner.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    private func configureView() {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = viewModel
        tableView.dataSource = viewModel
    }

    // MARK: - Output
    private func beginLoadingRepositories() {
        spinner.startAnimating()
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    }

    private func failedToLoadSearchRepositories() {
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.backgroundView = TUCEmptyTableViewBackground()
    }

    private func finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories() {
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    private func openUserDetails(userUrl: URL) {
        openUserDetails.send(userUrl)
    }

    private func openRepositoryDetails(repository: TUCRepository) {
        openRepositoryDetails.send(repository)
    }
}

// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate
extension TUCRepositoryListView: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        input.send(.searchButtonPress(withText: searchController.searchBar.text))
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        input.send(.searchButtonPress(withText: searchBar.text))
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        input.send(.cancelButtonPressed)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        input.send(.sortPressed(selectedIndex: selectedScope))
    }
}
```

Here is the `TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel`:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

/// A viewModel that fetches all repositories and searches for them using searchController.
/// The viewModel is also responsible for sorting/filtering results based on selected index of ScopeButton.
final class TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel: NSObject {
    enum Input {
        case searchButtonPress(withText: String?)
        case cancelButtonPressed
        case sortPressed(selectedIndex: Int)
    }
    enum Output {
        case didBeginLoading
        case failedToLoadSearchRepositories
        case finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories
        case openUserDetails(userUrl: URL)
        case openRepositoryDetils(repository: TUCRepository)
    }

    enum SortType {
        case stars
        case forks
        case updated

        init(_ index: Int) {
            switch index {
            case 0: self = .stars
            case 1: self = .forks
            case 2: self = .updated
            default: self = .stars
            }
        }
    }

    private var sortType: SortType = .stars
    private var lastSearchName = ""
    private var isLoadingSearchRepositories = false
    private var shouldInitialScreenPresent = true

    private var cellViewModels: [TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel] = []
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private let output = PassthroughSubject<Output, Never>()

    private var repositories: [TUCRepository] = [] {
        didSet {
            sortRepositories()
        }
    }
    private var sortedRepositories: [TUCRepository] = [] {
        didSet {
            cellViewModels.removeAll()
            for repository in sortedRepositories {
                let viewModel = TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel(repository: repository)
                cellViewModels.append(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Implementation
    func transform(input: AnyPublisher<Input, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Never> {
        input.sink { [weak self] event in
            switch event {
            case .searchButtonPress(withText: let name):
                self?.fetchRepositories(using: name)
            case .sortPressed(selectedIndex: let index):
                self?.sortType = .init(index)
                self?.sortRepositories()
            case .cancelButtonPressed:
                self?.cancelButtonPressed()
            }
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
        return output.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private func sortRepositories() {
        switch sortType {
        case .stars:
            sortedRepositories = repositories.sorted(by: { $0.stargazersCount > $1.stargazersCount })
        case .forks:
            sortedRepositories = repositories.sorted(by: { $0.forksCount > $1.forksCount })
        case .updated:
            let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
            sortedRepositories = repositories.sorted {
                guard let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: $0.updatedAt),
                      let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: $1.updatedAt) else {
                    return false
                }
                return firstDate > secondDate
            }
            // MARK: [TEST] - Uncomment to print sorted array of dates since "TURepository.updatedAt" is not preseneted on UI.
            // print(sortedRepositories.compactMap { return $0.updatedAt })
        }
        output.send(.finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories)
    }

    private func cancelButtonPressed() {
        shouldInitialScreenPresent = true
        repositories.removeAll()
    }

    private func fetchRepositories(using searchName: String?) {
        guard let name = searchName, !name.isEmpty else { return }
        if !isLoadingSearchRepositories && lastSearchName != name {
            let queryParams = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: name)
            ]
            let tucRequest = TUCRequest(enpoint: .searchRepositories, queryParams: queryParams)
            lastSearchName = name
            isLoadingSearchRepositories = true
            shouldInitialScreenPresent = false
            output.send(.didBeginLoading)
            TUCService.shared.execute(tucRequest, expected: TUCRepositoriesResponse.self)
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
                    if case .failure(let error) = completion {
                        self?.repositories.removeAll()
                        self?.isLoadingSearchRepositories = false
                        self?.output.send(.failedToLoadSearchRepositories)
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
                    self?.repositories = result.items
                    self?.isLoadingSearchRepositories = false
                    self?.output.send(.finishedLoadingOrSortingRepositories)
                }).store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
extension TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if cellViewModels.isEmpty && shouldInitialScreenPresent {
            tableView.backgroundView = TUCEmptyTableViewBackground(message: "Try searching for repo.")
            return 0
        }
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return cellViewModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell.identifier) as? TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        cell.userTapAction.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink { [weak self] userUrl in
            self?.output.send(.openUserDetails(userUrl: userUrl))
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
        cell.repositoryTapAction.sink { [weak self] repository in
            self?.output.send(.openRepositoryDetils(repository: repository))
        }.store(in: &cancellables)

        cell.configure(with: cellViewModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
}
```

Here is the `TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import SnapKit
import Combine

/// A table view cell that represents a repository item in a TURepositoryListView.
/// Press on image opens user details, press on text open repo details.
class TUCRepositoryListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "TURepositoryListTableViewCell"
    private var viewModel: TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel?

    public let userTapAction = PassthroughSubject<URL, Never>()
    public let repositoryTapAction = PassthroughSubject<TUCRepository, Never>()

    private let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    private let textContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    private let repositoryNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .semibold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let authorNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let numberOfWatchersLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let numberOfForksLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let numberOfIssuesLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let numberOfStarsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    private let authorAvatarImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    // MARK: - Init
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpViews()
        setUpConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Unsupported")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {}

    // MARK: - Implementation
    private func setUpViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubviews(authorAvatarImageView,
                                  textContainerView)
        textContainerView.addSubviews(repositoryNameLabel,
                                      authorNameLabel,
                                      numberOfForksLabel,
                                      numberOfIssuesLabel,
                                      numberOfWatchersLabel,
                                      numberOfStarsLabel)

        let tapImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openUserDetails))
        let tapText = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openRepositoryDetails))
        authorAvatarImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage)
        authorAvatarImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapText)
        textContainerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    private func setUpConstraints() {
        containerView.backgroundColor = .cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        }
        authorAvatarImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.width.equalTo(containerView.snp.height)
        }
        textContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.equalTo(authorAvatarImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
            make.top.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        repositoryNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.right.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(authorAvatarImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
        authorNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
            make.top.equalTo(repositoryNameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(2)
            make.left.equalTo(authorAvatarImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
        numberOfWatchersLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(authorNameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(5)
            make.left.equalTo(authorAvatarImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
        numberOfForksLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(numberOfWatchersLabel.snp.top)
            make.left.equalTo(numberOfWatchersLabel.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
        numberOfIssuesLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(numberOfWatchersLabel.snp.bottom).offset(2)
            make.left.equalTo(authorAvatarImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
        numberOfStarsLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(numberOfForksLabel.snp.bottom).offset(2)
            make.left.equalTo(numberOfIssuesLabel.snp.right).offset(10)
        }
    }

    public func configure(with viewModel: TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        repositoryNameLabel.text = viewModel.repositoryTitle
        authorNameLabel.text = viewModel.authorName
        numberOfWatchersLabel.text = viewModel.watchersCountText
        numberOfForksLabel.text = viewModel.forksCountText
        numberOfIssuesLabel.text = viewModel.issuesCountText
        numberOfStarsLabel.text = viewModel.starsCountText

        let placeholder = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
        authorAvatarImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        authorAvatarImageView.kf.setImage(with: viewModel.avatarURL,
                                          placeholder: placeholder,
                                          options: [.transition(.flipFromLeft(0.2))])
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc private func openUserDetails() {
        guard let url = viewModel?.userUrl else { return }
        userTapAction.send(url)
    }

    @objc private func openRepositoryDetails() {
        guard let repository = viewModel?.detailedRepository else { return }
        repositoryTapAction.send(repository)
    }
}
```

Here is the `TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel`:

```
import Foundation

/// A viewModel responsible for managing data of TURepositoryListTableViewCell.
final class TUCRepositoryListTableViewCellViewModel {
    private let repository: TUCRepository

    // MARK: - Public calculated properties
    public var id: Int {
        return repository.id
    }
    public var avatarURL: URL? {
        return URL(string: repository.ownerUser.avatarImageString)
    }
    public var repositoryTitle: String {
        return repository.name
    }
    public var authorName: String {
        return repository.ownerUser.name
    }
    public var userUrl: URL? {
        return URL(string: repository.ownerUser.userUrl)
    }
    public var repositoryUrl: String {
        return repository.repositoryUrl
    }
    public var starsCountText: String {
        return "Stars: \(repository.stargazersCount)"
    }
    public var watchersCountText: String {
        return "Watchers: \(repository.watchersCount)"
    }
    public var forksCountText: String {
        return "Forks: \(repository.forksCount)"
    }
    public var issuesCountText: String {
        return "Open issues: \(repository.openIssuesCount)"
    }
    public var detailedRepository: TUCRepository {
        return repository
    }

    // MARK: - Init
    init(repository: TUCRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }
}
```

I tried defining a protocol

```
protocol TUCRepositoryListViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func openUserDetails(url: URL)
    func openRepositoryDetails(repository: TUCRepository)
}

final class TUCRepositoryListView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: TUCRepositoryListViewDelegate?
.
.
.
```

and using the delegate pattern inside of the `TUCRepositoryListView` which worked, but I wish to get rid of the delegates for good.

Here is an example that worked:

```
final class TUCRepositoryListView: UIView {
.
.
.
    private func openUserDetails(userUrl: URL) {
        delegate?.openUserDetails(url: userUrl)
    }

    private func openRepositoryDetails(repository: TUCRepository) {
        delegate?.openRepositoryDetails(repository: repository)
    }
```

and extending the `TUCSearchRepoListViewController` like this:

```
extension TUCSearchRepoListViewController: TUCRepositoryListViewDelegate {
    func openRepositoryDetails(repository: TUCRepository) {
        let viewModel = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewModel(repository: repository)
        let vc = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func openUserDetails(url: URL) {
        let viewModel = TUCUserDetailsViewModel(userUrl: url)
        let vc = TUCUserDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you debug it? How far did you get? Are the functions you are expecting to be called even hit?

Comment: Yup, debugged, this is how it works:
Subject of 'userTapAction' send a notification that is being observed in the cellForRow inside of the 'TUCRepositroyListViewViewModel'. After receiving that notification, I'm calling the 'self?.output.send(.openUserDetails(userUrl: userUrl))'.
That is received in 'bind()' function of 'TUCRepositoryListView'. From 'bind()', next function is 'openUserDetails', also inside of the  'TUCRepositoryListView'. This one gets called, and the 'openUserDetails.send(userUrl)' inside does nothing.
I expect it to notify 'bind' in TUCSearchRepoListViewController @burnsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your project.

If we call `bind()` when setting up the views, shown in the code below, the PassThroughSubjects defined by `openUserDetails` and `openRepositoryDetails` can send the user or repository details to the subscribers in TUCSearchRepoListViewController on an event. The view controller will then produce your desired navigation using pushViewController().

In `TUCSearchRepoListViewController.swift`:

```swift
    private func setUpViews() {
        navigationItem.searchController = repoListView.searchController
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(repoListView)
        repoListView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
        bind() // <-- start observing UI events
    } 

    private func bind() {
        repoListView.openRepositoryDetails
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] repository in
                let viewModel = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewModel(repository: repository)
                let vc = TUCRepositoryDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
        repoListView.openUserDetails
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] url in
                let viewModel = TUCUserDetailsViewModel(userUrl: url)
                let vc = TUCUserDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

In `TUCRepositoryListView.swift`:

```
final class TUCRepositoryListView: UIView {

    ...

    public let openUserDetails = PassthroughSubject<URL, Never>()
    public let openRepositoryDetails = PassthroughSubject<TUCRepository, Never>()

    ...

    private func openUserDetails(userUrl: URL) {
        openUserDetails.send(userUrl)
    }

    private func openRepositoryDetails(repository: TUCRepository) {
        openRepositoryDetails.send(repository)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The main issue is that I did't call the bind() function in TUCSearchRepoListViewController. A stupid mistake on my part. @Daniel Zhang

Comment: Not stupid at all, but an excellent example of transitioning away from delegates into Combine.